Generalization of Koszul cohomology for wedge product with a fixed q-form: literature and references?
Let $A$ be a commutative ring. For an odd positive integer $q$ and an integer $p$ in the range $1 \leq p \leq q$, consider the cochain complex:
$0 \to \Lambda^p(A^N) \to \Lambda^{p+q}(A^N) \to \cdots \to \Lambda^{p+\lfloor (N-p)/q \rfloor q}(A^N) \to 0$
with the differential $d: \Lambda^n(A^N) \to \Lambda^{n+q}(A^N)$ defined by:
$d(\omega) = C_q \wedge \omega,$
where $C_q$ is a fixed $q$-form in $\Lambda^q(A^N)$.
For $q = 1$, this construction recovers the Koszul cochain complex and its associated Koszul cohomology. I am curious whether the cohomology for larger $q$ (i.e., $q > 1$) has been studied in the literature.
If so, I would appreciate any references, names, or keywords that might help me explore this further. Thank you in advance for any insights or pointers!

Welcome new contributor.  Denote the standard basis of $A^N$ by $(\mathbf{e}_1,\dots,\mathbf{e}_N)$, and assume that $N\geq 4$.  Let $C_2$ be $\left( \mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2\right) + \left(\mathbf{e}_3\wedge \mathbf{e}_4\right)$.  Then $C_2 \wedge C_2$ equals $2\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2\wedge \mathbf{e}_3\wedge \mathbf{e}_4$.  This need not equal zero.

Thanks for your comment. q should be an odd integer. I’m sorry if I didn’t emphasize this point enough in my post.

Sorry, I missed that $q$ is odd.
